# Errors while running meteor project on android device

Tags: android, meteor

```
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:
```

While adding plugin
   https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet.git#df5e89e54d5142c964c1139db6fe813a01125825
   to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin
   https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet.git via git.
   Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:
   Error: git: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
   xcrun: error: invalid active developer path
   (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
   at plugins.clonePluginGit.fail.then.pinfo
   (/Users/omiharjani/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:88:33)
   at _rejected
   (/Users/omiharjani/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
   at
   /Users/omiharjani/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
   at Promise.when
   (/Users/omiharjani/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
   (/Users/omiharjani/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
   at
   /Users/omiharjani/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
   at flush
   (/Users/omiharjani/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not 
   apply to the Meteor integration. You can try running again with the
   --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command solved the above error: `xcode-select --install`